# C how can I call an program over system and pause that program?

Tags: c, windows

I want to write an wrapper around robocops that allows the program to be paused at any time? If I call the program over system(), how can I terminate and pause it?

Comment: If you are talking about some function like the modern firewalls do, so please add more info will be helpful to help you.

Comment: To begin with, `system` is a *blocking* function. It won't return until the program you run have ended. If you need greater control over the processes you start then you need to use the [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) Windows function. That *might* allow you to temporarily *suspend* the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options:

- You can use the "system" function call to use command prompt to call the function to pause, but the use may just click "enter" and it will keep moving -> system("pause");
- You may use threads in order to to stop your program from moving on but it is harder and you have to learn how to use them.